# How do I point 'Like' URL to ID on portfolio collection page, rather than single page?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, facebook-like

I've got a Wordpress site with a [Portfolio page](http://universalfavourite.com.au/our-work/). For each Portfolio piece I want a FB Like button. Easy enough. Here's the sneaky bit:

Usually in a simular setting, e.g. a blog, you set the Like URL to point to the single article page of the post it's attached to. But for this Portfolio there aren't any single pages, the Portfolio is only the one page. The URL should point to the specific post's ID, e.g. http://example.com/our-work/#post-244, rather than (the non-existent) http://example.com/our-work/new-client-print.html

This took me 20 minutes to set up for the Tweet button on the page, but I'm on my 3rd day trying to get this going for Facebook Like.

The best idea I've come up with is setting up a Portfolio article page, then set a .htaccess to reroute to the full page. But the variables would be to random, so I'm not even attempting that, and the URL that gets displayed on Facebook would be incorrect.

As usual the deadline is today, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

I sort of got it working, but ended up not using it at all. I'll explain at the end.

I copied the code in the article template that I'm using to add the `id="post-##"`.

In my case that's  within the loop. So my fb:like looked like this:

```
<fb:like href="http://example.com/our-work/#post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" layout="box_count" show_faces="false" width="70" colorscheme="light"></fb:like>
```

I also needed to get the meta `og:url` code pointing to the all these extra URL's for the Like'ing to work. For this I used

```
<?php 
    global $post;
    $tmp_post = $post;
    $args = array('post_type' => 'work'); 
    $custom_posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach($custom_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
?>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/our-work/#post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"/>
<?php
    endforeach;
    $post = $tmp_post;
?>
```

Facebook Linter doesn't really like the multiple og:url's, but it still works.

*But*, having done this the URL will point correctly, but I was still missing getting the correct image, title and description. I could've maybe used the same loop, but not sure how well that would've worked for the validation. And I'd end up with one massive list of meta...

Hopefully this might help somebody later.

Answer (score 1):

You got to add each #hash as a separate meta `og:url` property

- http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=251799
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/
- http://pastie.org/2837144

The only drawback from this solution is that the `og:title` and `og:description` are the same for all the sections in the page and can not be switched, without some extra magic trough js in combination with server side detection that could detected that the page is being picked up by the Facebook or other social sharing service with a given `#hash`-tag

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go. Didn't realise I could have multiple og:url's. I'd still like it to load the different og:title, og:description and og:image, but that seems like rather overhead now.